# Is there a way to build cscope database for opencv?

Tags: opencv, cscope

I haven't used cscope much. I would like to know the instructions to build (database) and use cscope with opencv. 
Also, Is it applicable only to C programs? how about C++?

Comment: This might help too - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917923/how-to-use-cscope-for-a-project-which-has-c-cpp-and-h-files

Answer (score 0):

I found this long dead question as I searched for the same topic.  Here's what I've found.

According to the [cscope home page](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/)

> The fuzzy parser supports C, but is flexible enough to be useful for C++ and Java, and for use as a generalized 'grep database' (use it to browse large text documents!)

So, I went ahead and generated a cscope database for opencv2, more or less adapting from the [cscope large projects tutorial](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/large_projects.html)

in order to generate the appropriate cscope.files, if searching the OCV2 directory below, you'd run the find command, pruning out a lot of superfluous directories and files.

```
#!/bin/bash
OCV2=~/src/opencv/opencv
find $OCV2 -path "$OCV2*/.git" -prune -o -path "$OCV2*/samples" -prune -o -path "$OCV2*/cmake" -prune -o  -path "$OCV2*/data" -prune -o  -path "$OCV2*/doc" -prune -o  -path "$OCV2*/platforms" -prune -o  -path "$OCV2*/release" -prune -o  -iname "*\.cpp" -print -o -iname "*\.hpp" -print -o -iname "*\.c" -print -o  -iname "*\.h" -print > cscope.files
```

Now, you'll want to generate the cscope database, do so by running the following from within the same directory as cscope.files

`cscope -b -q -k`

which will create the files:
`cscope.in.out  cscope.out  cscope.po.out`

If you have the environment variable $CSCOPE_DB set to point at `cscope.out` then you'll be ready to go.

Let me know if you have any other questions.